# Check for same password and confirm password in Angular Reactive Form - FormBuilder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formbuilder

I'm trying to create Angular 5 registration form with .NET Core.

I'm checking whether password and retyped password are the same in the registration form. I'm using ***FormBuilder*** for form.

But checking password1 and password2 is always failing. I have tried `===` also.

```
if (this.RegistrationForm.valid) {
  if (this.RegistrationForm.get('password1') == this.RegistrationForm.get('password2')) {
    this.MyService.Register(this.RegistrationForm.value).subscribe((data) => {}, error => this.errorMessage = error)
  } else {
    this.errorMessage = "cdscs";
  }
}

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private MyService: RoadSignService) {
        this.RegistrationForm = this.fb.group({
            Id: 0,
            name: ['', [Validators.required]],
            email: ['', [Validators.required]],
            gender: ['', [Validators.required]],
            department: ['', [Validators.required]],
            address: ['', [Validators.required]],
            password1: ['', [Validators.required]],
            password2: ['', [Validators.required]]
        })
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: i have tried that. but no help from that

Comment: Please `console.log(this.RegistrationForm.get('password1'), this.RegistrationForm.get('password2'));` and post the result here.

Comment: You need to debug with console.log first, do that line and check what's wrong, maybe it's extra space. `console.log(this.RegistrationForm.get('password1'), this.RegistrationForm.get('password2'), this.RegistrationForm.get('password1') == this.RegistrationForm.get('password2'))`

Comment: CAn you post your HTML and the formbuilder code?

Comment: false for console.log(this.RegistrationForm.get('password1') == this.RegistrationForm.get('password2')); but individually shows same value

Comment: Code attached @Niladri

Comment: Where's the part where you do `==` or `===` in the code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once your user submits the form, the form value will be available as a JSON Object in `this.RegistrationForm.value`. So you can use that to make the comparison.

Just use `this.RegistrationForm.value.password1 === this.RegistrationForm.value.password2`

```
if (this.RegistrationForm.valid) {
  if (this.RegistrationForm..value.password1 === this.RegistrationForm.value.password2) {
    this.MyService.Register(this.RegistrationForm.value)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {}, 
        error => this.errorMessage = error
      )
  } else {
    this.errorMessage = "cdscs";
  }
}
```

**PS:** If you want to create a Custom Validator that does this, [**please refer to this OP**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44449802/2622292).

Comment: I have used get password1() { return this.RegistrationForm.value.password1; }. Is there a problem with this in comparison @SiddAjmera

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as a validator across the entire FormGroup, rather than submit the form, then do the check.

When you define the FormGroup, you can add a validator for the entire group, giving you access to all of the controls/values as such:

```
validatePasswords(formGroup: FormGroup): any {
    const password = formGroup.controls['password'];
    const confirmPassword = formGroup.controls['confirmPassword'];

    // don't validate
    if (password.pristine || confirmPassword.pristine) {
      return null;
    }

    formGroup.markAsTouched();

    if (password.value === confirmPassword.value) {
      return null;
    }

    return confirmPassword.setErrors({
      notEqual: true
    });
  }

form = this.formBuilder.group({
  . . .,
  password: [
    '', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(regexPatterns.password),
    ]
  ],
  confirmPassword: [
    '', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(regexPatterns.password)
    ]
  ]
}, {
  validator: this.validatePasswords
});
```

In this example, `regexPatterns.password` is just a shared import of RegExp objects, and the expression is: `/^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=*]).*/`

Now you can show the user if the two fields match *before* you submit the form and invoke any other logic, API calls or any expensive operations.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best approach here would be adding a custom validator to compare both passwords, e.g:

```
// Custom validator
function validateRePassword(control: FormControl){
  const { root } = control;
  const pass = root.get('password'),
        rePass = root.get('rePassword');

  if(!pass || !rePass) {
    return null;
  }

  const passVal = pass.value,
        rePassVal = rePass.value;

  const result = passVal===rePassVal ? null : { passDontMatch: true };
  return result;
}

// Form initialization
this.formGroup = fb.group({
      user: fb.control('UserName'),
      password: fb.control(''),
      rePassword: fb.control('', [validateRePassword])
    })

// function to check if the control has the 'passDontMatch' error and therefore display some related message
passMatch(){
    return !this.formGroup.get('rePassword').hasError('passDontMatch');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom validator didn't work for me, even with a custom state matcher.

I'm checking password with hand.

```
<input type="password" formControlName="password" (input)="checkPasswordsMatch()">
<input type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword" (input)="checkPasswordsMatch()">
<p class="error" *ngIf="form.get('confirmPassword').hasError('notSame')"> It works </p>
```

```
checkPasswordsMatch(): void {
  const password = this.form.get('password');
  const confirmPassword = this.form.get('confirmPassword');

  if (password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
    this.form.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({ notSame: true });
  }
}
```