# Password and confirm password validation in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement password and confirm password validation in an angular project. I followed the answer on this post [Confirm password validation in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605737/confirm-password-validation-in-angular-6).
However I am unable to get any error message. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
here is my ts code:

```
  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder,private userService:UsersService,private router:Router) { }
  addForm: FormGroup;
  selected = 'option2';
  passwordsMatcher = new RepeatPasswordEStateMatcher;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      password:new FormControl( '',[ Validators.required]),
      passwordAgain: new FormControl('',[ Validators.required]),
      userRole:['',Validators.required],

    },{ validator: RepeatPasswordValidator });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.addForm.valid)
    {
    this.userService.createUser(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.router.navigate(['newuser']);
      });
    console.log(this.addForm.controls.password.value);
  }
}
  changeClient(value) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(this.addForm.controls.value);
}
```

here is my validator code:

```
export class RepeatPasswordEStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return (control && control.parent.get('password').value !== control.parent.get('passwordAgain').value)
  }
}
export function RepeatPasswordValidator(group: FormGroup) {
  let password = group.controls.password.value;
  let passwordConfirmation = group.controls.passwordAgain.value;

  return password === passwordConfirmation ? null: { passwordsNotEqual: true }     
}
```

Below is my template:

```
<div  style="height: 100vh" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
    <h2 class="text-center">Add User</h2>
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-content>

    <form [formGroup]="addForm" class="login-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">

      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="userName" placeholder="userName" name="userName" class="form-control" id="userName">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">

      <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password">
      <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.controls.password.hasError('required')" >Passwords can't be empty</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="passwordAgain" placeholder="Confirm the password" type="password" [errorStateMatcher]="passwordsMatcher">
        <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.controls.passwordAgain.hasError('passwordsNotEqual')" >Passwords are different. They should be equal!</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Roles" formControlName="userRole" id="userRole" (selectionChange)="changeClient($event.value)" [(value)]="selected">
          <mat-option value="Admin">Admin</mat-option>


        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <div class="container" style="margin: 12px" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">


    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Create</button>
      </div>
  </form>
  </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check `isErrorState` method return value ?  , i guess it will be not a boolean , check it please by logging it is return value

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449673/custom-validator-on-reactive-form-for-password-and-confirm-password-matching-get

Comment: @rock11, you must return **null** not false, if a validator is OK

Comment: @Eliseo made it null, still no change.

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID I logged the value,I'm getting bollean return

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the equality of the two fields `password` and `passwordAgain`in the `matcher` which is already done in `validator`,

The work of the `matcher` is to check if the error Message should be shown or not, in your case the error message should appear when `addForm` has an `passwordsNotEqual`.

Since the validator is applied on the `FormGroup` not on the `FormControl` so in the matcher you have to check the validity of the `FormGroup`.

So what i suggest is to modify `isErrorState` method like this :

```
isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!(control && control.parent && control.parent.invalid && control.parent.dirty);
}
```

And In HTML you should check the `formGroup` errors not `formControl`.( because again the validator is applied on `addForm` not on `passwordAgain`)

```
    <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.hasError('passwordsNotEqual')" >Passwords are different. They should be equal!</mat-error>
    <!-- instead of addForm.controls.passwordAgain.hasError('passwordsNotEqual') -->
```

This will for sure work for you.