# Create a custom validator to validate against multiple form fields

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation, angular-validator

I have the following form setup:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  ...
  year: new FormControl("", validateDateMethod(year, month, day)),
  month: new FormControl("", validateDateMethod(year, month, day)),
  day: new FormControl("", validateDateMethod(year, month, day))
});
```

I want to create a custom validator to validate the date based on the 3 fields.

Is it possible to create a validator based on multiple form values?

Normal customs validators just take in the current control and any parameter values.

Thanks

Comment: Please look into code in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44449802/3875919

Comment: I've tried something similar to that but I receive an error: Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'validator' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions

Comment: I need to use form builder to clear the error

Comment: You could achieve by setting the custom property in the errors object of the `FormControl` and then display the error message in the DOM using `*ngIf` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group all the three dates to a formgroup and add validator to it. Then you can validate across all the three fields.

```
 this.form = new FormGroup({
      ...
      dateGroup:this.formBuilder.group({
      year: new FormControl(""),
      month: new FormControl(""),
      day: new FormControl("")
    },{validator:validateDates}) 
  });

    validateDates(c:AbstractControl){
    const year = c.get('year');
    const month = c.get('month');
    const day = c.get('day');
    ....
    }
```

Comment: you need to pass the whole formGroup as argument to access to all controls :validateDates(c:FormGroup)

Comment: It wont create problem because FormGroup extends AbstractControl

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.